# AES encryption versus decryption speed

Tags: encryption, openssl, aes

I had read somewhere the decryption can be performed faster than encryption. Is this correct? This would be a pure software implementation using may be openssl.

Comment: If somebody could refresh my mind: I did hear that some symmetric algorithm did have *slightly* better performance when decrypting because of some kind of memory or register issue. Because of this decryption could be used instead of encryption for stream ciphers (as Jim helpfully provided as example). I don't think it's relevant for AES within OpenSSL though. It's maybe more of a question for [crypto](http://crypto.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The block cipher mode of operation might have a direct impact in the performance of the encryption/decryption processes. Roughly speaking; the operations performed on each round while AES is encrypting a block of data are performed in the opposite direction (decryption), so no reasonable justification for performance variation in the encryption/decryption itself , however; some of the block cipher mode of operations (e.g. CBC) requires sequential operation when encrypting input blocks, while no need for sequential operation in decryption.
Please Check this link for further discussion on this matter:
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38055/why-does-aes-encryption-take-more-time-than-decryption

Answer (score 5):

AES is a symmetric encryption, and is the same speed whether encrypting or decrypting. In fact in some streaming modes, AES simply generates a stream of bits that are xored with the data to encrypt, with the reciever running the exact same AES to produce the exact same bitstream to xor in to decrypt.

Comment: ghostkadost, this is a perfectly valid answer, regardless of my little tag on, I would advise you to accept it...

Comment: I think the AES inverse cipher used when decrypting in some modes like CBC is a bit more computationally intensive. As I understand it's because the inverse mix columns step uses more multiplications, when encrypting some minx columns multiplications are n*1.

Comment: Or more table lookups if the multiplication is done using precomputed tables.